# BigBlueButton getting unusaul traffic

Tags: networking, ubuntu-16.04, traffic, attacks

We are running a bare-metal server which can handle 400 concurrent video conferencing users. We are using BigBlueButton application for video conferencing. It was running smoothly for the past 6 months. Last 2 weeks we having a strange high peak in network even when user count is bellow 200.

At that time we can't access ssh also. Is this a attack how can we traceout the issue?

Our servers are in Germany and main user cluster is at UAE.

I am a webdevloper, sorry if I missed anything to mention in the questions.
[image]

Comment: Have you upgraded to the latest version to fix the numerous security vulnerabilities?

Comment: Yes  our current bbb version is  2.2.25

Comment: Based on your tag the system uses Ubuntu16.04. Big Blue button is know to install third party software on that system that does no longer receive security updates. I would recommend to update the system to 20.04. As you are from Germany there was just an article (in German) on golem.de about the insecurities of Big Blue Button - I would read it carefully.

Comment: But for running bigbluebutton they are recommending ubuntu 16.04, it won't install in other versions of ubuntu. I tried in 18 and 20. PS I am not from Germany, servers are at Germany :)